# Onsubmit Function Disabled in Wordpress Forms. Why?

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation

I have a simple HTML form that captures someone's name, email address, company name, and a few other items. I want to use onsubmit to run my form validation function before the data is submitted to my MYSQL database.

I have the form built inside of a text box using Wordpress Visual Composer. When I update the box, the form stays put, and works, but any call such as onsubmit, onclick etc.. get stripped out, regardless of what I name the function.

Why does this happen, and how do I get around it to create a form validation function for my basic forms?

Thank you,
- Joe